# Is there a way to use gulp to remove all instances of require.js define([...]) wrappers?

Tags: javascript, regex, npm, gulp

I would like to test my app without require.js to see what the performance and file size would be like as a single concatenated file.

I'm thinking of using gulp to grab all app *.js files, perform a gulp-replace to remove all instances of the the `define([...], function (...) { });` wrapper in the script, and the concatenate into a single *.js file.

Any idea if gulp-replace could handle that, and if so, what would the regex look like? Here's an example of a *.js file:

```
'use strict';

define(['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], function (param1, param2, param3) {
    //...
    //code that should remain after gulp-replace
    //...
});
```

Comment: r.js can bundle them for you...

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried a whole bunch of npm gulp r.js optimizers and I couldn't get any of them work. Eventually I just used gulp-replace to strip the define wrapper from the *.js files targeted by gulp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution for anyone else attempting to try the same:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  replace = require('gulp-replace'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', '!src/main.conf.js', '!src/**/*_test.js'])
  .pipe(replace(/'use strict';/g, ''))
  .pipe(replace(/define\s?\(\[.*\],\s?function\s?\(.*\)\s?\{/g, ''))
  .pipe(replace(/\}\)\;\s?$/g, ''))
  .pipe(concat('app.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Assumption is that you are only targeting require.js files. If you have compile errors, try using gulp-debug to figure out which file is throwing the errors.

Assumption is that it doesn't matter which order these files load in, which is the case with an AngularJS app. But if order is important, you can set the desired order in the array you pass into gulp.src.

Comment: `.pipe(replace(/'use strict';/g, ''))` neat! I've been [banging](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/248) [my head](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remove-use-strict) trying to do this